# How to use onmouseover in StyledDocumend assosiated with a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, mouseover, jtextpane, styleddocument

I want to highlight different sections of text when mouse is hovered over them. I'm currently using styleddocument with jTextPane. Can somebody please help me in defining style so that individual strings/paragraphs can be highlighted when mouseover occurs?

Thanks,

Comment: could be interesting question, but based on your SSCCE or MCVE or  MCTaRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom highlighter to show necessary colors. Add a `MouseListener` to the jTextPane. You can get mouse coordinates and use `viewToModel()` method of jTextPane to detect offset in the `Document` and process whether current section should be highlighted or not.